# is it possible to have two or more merged configuration files in a project?

Tags: asp.net, merge, web-config

i am using [ELMAH - Error Logging Modules And Handlers For ASP.NET](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) in my project!
is there a way for put elmah's configuration in a separate web.config file?
mean is it possible to have two or more merged configuration files in a project?

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So long as you use the `configSource` attribute, you can use as many different files as you want.

It is common to all configuration sections (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx)).

Assuming your section group is named `elmah`, you can do the following:

```
<elmah configSource="elmah.config" />
```

Comment: Really thanks for answer, but what about <system.web><httpModules> in elmah's config file. should i add them to my main web.config file or is not necessary?

Comment: @MoonLight - That will still need to go in the `web.config`, as it is _not_ part of the `elmah` configuration section. It is how the ELMAH HTTP Module is setup.

Comment: is it possible to put them in elmah.config?

Comment: i want to have a separate web configuration file (for elmah) for using in other projects!

Comment: @MoonLight - No. The ELMAH configuration section doesn't support modules. You _can_ to setup the modules in a different file, but this will be different from the `elmah.config`.

Comment: @MoonLight - You can't have _all_ parts in a single file, simply because it is configured in several _different_ configuration sections, and it is only possible to have one file _per_ configuration section.

Comment: This doesn't work Really. Downvoted, sorry. `configSource` is not supported on elmah element, beside your documentation link is dead.